# Conflict between dependencies when adding a new one

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

These were my dependencies in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  dependencies:
   ...
   image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
   ...
```

And everything worked fine, but now I added this:

```
  dependencies:
   ...
   image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
   ...
   image_editor_pro: ^1.1.8
```

And running pub get I have this error:

> Because image_editor_pro >=1.1.0 depends on image_picker ^0.7.4 and provauth depends on image_picker ^0.8.4+2, image_editor_pro >=1.1.0 is forbidden.
> So, because provauth depends on image_editor_pro ^1.1.8, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because provauth depends on image_editor_pro ^1.1.8, version solving failed.)

I tried downgrading my version of image_picker but I get a new error:

> Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\loren\flutter.pub-cache_temp\dir60565baa\test\fixtures\invalid\n_structure_<.>.json' (OS Error: Syntax of the name of the file, of the directory or of volume is not correct (This is my bad translation of the error).
> , errno = 123)
> pub get failed (66; , errno = 123))

What can I do to solve and use both the dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to override the dependency so only one version is used for your project. Something like this:

```
name: your_app

dependencies:
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  image_editor_pro: ^1.1.8

dependency_overrides:
  image_picker: '0.8.4+2'  # Use only this version for all the code depended on image picker
```

But you need to thoroughly tested the library that depends on the overrided dependency to check if it not introducing you a new error.

See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a conflict with image_editor_pro because the package is old.

It is better to look for another updated package with null safety, like image_editor 1.0.2, this won't have conflictions with image_picker 0.8.4+1.

And if you are willing to downgrade. ## Downgrading is a pain

You might need to downgrade the other dependencies as well. which might lead to Downgrading the Dart version.

After downgrading execute this command:
`flutter clean`

Then delete pubspec.lock file.

Answer (score 1):

If a conflict between dependencies occurs, the simplest solution is to remove the version numbers of the two dependencies and then replace them with 'any' without the quotes in front of it. Then run `pub get`.
Hope you can help